# How to transfer the data from one table to another

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I have items table and low_stocks table 
I wanted to copy those datas from items table which has quantity less than 5
and I tried This

```
$items = Item::where('quantity','<',5)->get()->toArray();
foreach($items as $item)
   if($item['quantity'] == 0) {
      $boolean = true
   }
   $boolean = false
   LowStock::create([
     'item_id' => $items['id'],
     'out_of_stock' =>$boolean
   ]);
}
```

But it fails and returns error . How to do that

Comment: the $boolean is always false....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   $items = Item::where('quantity','<',5)->get()->toArray();
    foreach($items as $item){
       $boolean = false;
       if($item['quantity'] == 0) {
          $boolean = true;
       }
       LowStock::create([
         'item_id' => $item['id'],
         'out_of_stock' =>$boolean
       ]);
    }
```

there were some `;` missing, the `$boolean` was always false, and inside the `create()` method you was doing `$items[id]` instead of `$item[id]`

Also if you want, you can replace

```
$boolean = false;
if($item['quantity'] == 0) {
  $boolean = true
}
```

with

```
$boolean = ($item['quantity'] == 0);
```

which can be also done in this way

```
$boolean = !item['quantity']
```

(obvoiusly)